# I'm looking for a Mathematica solution to de Vaucouleurs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Anyone know where I can pick up a *Mathematica* solution to the de Vaucouleurs formula? I'm attempting to test a model against rotation curve data and I need a function that will calculate mass given a characteristic radius.  The general form of the equation is:$$\Sigma_b(r)=\Sigma_{be}\exp\left(-\kappa(\frac{r}{a_b})^{\frac{1}{4}}-1 \right)$$$$M_b=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}r\Sigma_b(r) dr=22.665 a_b^2 \Sigma_{be}$$$$\rho_b(r)=\int_r^\infty\frac{d\Sigma_b(x)}{dx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-r^2}}dx$$$$M_b(R)=4\pi\int_0^R\rho_b(r)r^2 dr$$Which doesn't seem to have an exact solution as far as I can tell in *Mathematica*.

Comment: What would be a typical example of $\Sigma_b(x)$?

Comment: I've updated the description of the problem to include the relevant relations.

Comment: ...and what are typical values of $\Sigma_{be}$, $\kappa$, and $a_b$?

Comment: In a solution found bo Y. Sofue.  $\kappa$ is constant at 7.6695.  $a_b$ is around 500 pc.  $\Sigma_{be}$ is $3.2 x 10^3 M$ Solar Masses.